# Passing selected text of dropdownlist through json

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, drop-down-menu, controller

I want to get the text of selected option from the dropdownlist in the controller method.
But with the below code, I get only the initial text not the changed text.

data.jsonOfLog which is before data.submit, gets the changed text, but it is not this text which is passed to the controller.

In Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GoodSave(string jsonOfLog)
{
```

In View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {                 
            json = { jsonOfLog: $("#ddlDocumentType option:selected").text() };
            $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: '/Home/GoodSave',
                data: JSON.stringify(json),
                add: function (e, data) {
                    $('#fileuploadbutton').click(function () { 
                        data.jsonOfLog = $("#ddlDocumentType option:selected").text();
                        data.submit();
                    })
                }                
            });
        });
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: Use `$("#ddlDocumentType").val()`

Comment: @Satpal - he wants the text, not the value.

Comment: @Archer, Read title `Passing selected value of dropdownlist through json`

Comment: @Satpal, Read code `.text()`.  You should be asking a question, not telling them something that may be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This will change the `formData` when you try to upload...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {                 
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: '/Home/GoodSave'
        })
        .on("fileuploadsubmit", function (e, data) {
            data.formData = {
                jsonOfLog: $("#ddlDocumentType option:selected").text()
            };
        });

        $("#fileuploadbutton").on("click", function() {
            $("#fileupload").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I don't think you need to stringify the data, so try the above and if that doesn't work then use stringify as you did previously.  It shouldn't be needed as you're passing the data with property names which should match the parameters in the server method.

This comes from the blueimp file upload documentation...

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I want the controller method to be called when "Upload" button is clicked. With your suggested change, it would be called on the click of "Choose File" button.

Comment: Okay - I shall amend.

Comment: Also, data.jsonOfLog which is before data.submit, gets the changed text, but it is not this text which is passed to the controller. The controller method gets the initial text of the dropdownlist.

Comment: Try that.  You were passing `data`, but according to the documentation on the file upload plugin you should be using `formData`.  I've only ever used it for file uploads before now so can't be too sure about adding form data as well, but that appears to be what you need to do.

Comment: But where is the click event of #fileuploadbutton specified in that script?

Comment: Added - give that a try and let us know how you get on.

Comment: With this code the controller method is not hit.
But if I put 
data: JSON.stringify({ jsonOfLog: $("#ddlDocumentType option:selected").text() }),
after
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
the controller method is hit, but on the click of "Choose File" button.

Comment: Can anyone please tell me how to retrieve formData in the controller method?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, what worked is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            add: function (e, data) {
                $('#fileuploadbutton').click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        cache: true,
                        url: '/Home/GoodSave',
                        data: { jsonOfLog: $("#ddlDocumentType option:selected").text() },
                        success: function (data) {

                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    });
                });
            }    
        });    
    });    
</script>
```